# pandas selecting max and min simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas

Give a dataframe like this:

```py
   count        date location  type
0    100  2018-01-01    site1  high
1     10  2018-01-01    site2   low
2     11  2018-01-01    site3   low
3    101  2018-01-03    site2  high
4    103  2018-01-03    site2  high
5     15  2018-01-03    site3   low
```

I need to find the highest and lowest count for each day (in mm-dd format, year is irrelevant).  The result I'm looking for is something like this:

```py
                count       date location
month-day type                           
01-01     high    100 2018-01-01    site1
          low      10 2018-01-01    site2
01-03     high    103 2018-01-03    site2
          low      15 2018-01-03    site3
```

I have a way that works, but I'm sure it can be cleaned up.  Here's what I've got currently:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-03'],
                   'location':['site1', 'site2', 'site3', 'site2', 'site2', 'site3'], 
                   'type':['high', 'low', 'low', 'high', 'high', 'low'], 
                   'count':[100, 10, 11, 101, 103, 15]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['month-day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%d')) 

maxCount = df.loc[df.groupby(['month-day']['type'=='high'])['count'].idxmax()]
minCount = df.loc[df.groupby(['month-day']['type'=='low'])['count'].idxmin()]

df = maxCount.merge(minCount, how='outer')
df.set_index(['month-day', 'type'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

These will eventually be used as input to matplotlib to chart count vs. month-day for both low and high, so it may actually make sense to keep them separate rather than joining them back together, but is there a better way to do this?  The groupby in particular seems kind of iffy with the `][`, but it does work.  The only things that I care about are month-day, type, and count (and type is only needed to know if it's low or high, so if I used a dedicated series for low and one for high I wouldn't need to keep type once I put month-day and count in the appropriate series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is complicated by the fact that you have already assigned highs and lows. Do you need to account for these? (Is one day's max labelled as a `low`?)
If not, you can go with something as simple as this:

```py
df.groupby(['month-day']).agg({ 'count': ['min', 'max'] })
```

Which would give you this:

```py
          count     
            min  max
month-day           
01-01        10  100
01-03        15  103
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  The data I'm working with already has high and low values defined explicitly as such (`low` and `high`), but if there is any case where something is tagged `low` but is actually the day's maximum, or vice versa, that's an error in the data.  The gist of the problem I was trying to solve is finding the absolute min and max per day when there are multiple sites, each reporting their own min and max.  I can't see any scenario where this won't do what I need.

Comment: I guess one corner case would be if one site's lowest `high` is lower than another site's highest `low`, but for what I'm working with I don't see that being likely.

Answer (score 0):

You were not really clear on the logic: should `type` be included? Based on what you have tried I am going to assume yes:

```
# groupby
group = df.groupby('month-day')['count']

# create your min and max logic for boolean indexing
min_log = ((df['count'] == group.transform(min)) & (df['type'] == 'low'))
max_log = ((df['count'] == group.transform(max)) & (df['type'] == 'high'))

# boolean indexing to filter df
df[ min_log | max_log]

        date location  type  count month-day
0 2018-01-01    site1  high    100     01-01
1 2018-01-01    site2   low     10     01-01
4 2018-01-03    site2  high    103     01-03
5 2018-01-03    site3   low     15     01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `agg`, `stack`, `loc` and `set_index`

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%m-%d')
m = df.groupby(s)['count'].agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin']).stack()
df_out = df.loc[m].set_index([m.index.droplevel(1), 'type'])

Out[127]:
                  date location  count
date  type
01-01 high  2018-01-01    site1    100
      low   2018-01-01    site2     10
01-03 high  2018-01-03    site2    103
      low   2018-01-03    site3     15
```